# Error with declaring variables with {} in C++

Tags: c++

I'm using C++. I tried to declare a variable like this:

```
int my_num {5};
```

I got an error in the logs:

"error: expected ';' at end of declaration"

I get the same error when I do this:

```
int my_arr [] {1,2,3,4};
```

I am new to C++ (normally work with JS). Any idea what's going on here?

c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)

Comment: The code looks fine. Are you compiling with at least c++11?

Comment: [Not reproduced](https://godbolt.org/z/5TG6xG)

Comment: On MacOS and with the compiler version you posted, you need the flag `-std=c++11` (or higher).

Comment: @lubgr that was the problem. Thanks!